# Cygwin running script from one batch file?

Tags: bash, batch-file, cygwin

I know when Cygwin installs there is a batch file that is used to launch it in Windows. But if I want to run a script without launching Cygwin and doing "./script"

How do I create a batch file to do that?

As in... just have one batch file that when clicked, opens Cygwin and runs the shell script.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

To run "foo.bsh", create a batch file with the following contents and run it:

```
    set PATH=C:\cygwin\bin;%PATH%
    c:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe c:\path\to\foo.bsh
```

The "C:\cygwin\bin" part can differ depending on your chosen install location of cygwin.

Comment: This doesn't work for me because when I run the command 'rf' in sh script

Answer (score 9):

You might try something like this to trampoline from CMD to BASH (or whatever sh-variant):

```
    : <<TRAMPOLINE
    @echo off
    bash -c "exit 0" || (echo.No bash found in PATH! & exit /b 1)
    bash "%~f0" "%*" 
    goto :EOF 
    TRAMPOLINE
    #####################
    #!/bin/bash  -- it's traditional!
    echo "Hello from $SHELL"
```

Comment: This worked nicely for me, but I found I had to use UNIX style line endings when saving the file to ensure that the bash script was happy.

Answer (score 9):

I'd like to expand on the answer given by Austin Hastings to allow it to work without Cygwin in the path and to work in the directory setup with the bat file (so even a shortcut with a different "Start in " path is used). The changes are to include full path to bash, use option `-l` to make bash setup properly with paths and environment and to pass the current directory to bash as the first argument which is popped of (using `shift`). Remember to use Unix newlines in the file or you will get lots of errors. Also use UTF8 instead of ANSI.

```
: <<TRAMPOLINE
@echo off
C:\cygwin\bin\bash -c "exit 0" || (echo.No bash found in PATH! & exit /b 1)
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%i in (%*) do set _args= !_args! "%%~i"
C:\cygwin\bin\bash -l "%~f0" "%CD%" %_args%
goto :EOF 
TRAMPOLINE
#####################
#!/bin/bash  -- it's traditional!
cd "$1"
shift
echo Working from $PWD
```

Edit: Fixed the trampoline code to pass arguments properly to bash. BAT files do not have a bash equivalent of "$@" and a loop processing each argument is made and then passed to bash.exe. Now properly handles arguments with spaces.

Comment: How do we exit from this command though? putting `exit /B` after `TRAMPOLINE` doesn't work.

Comment: Simply type `exit` as the environment after the `TRAMPOLINE` line is in `bash`. `exit /B` is a `cmd` command.

Comment: I asked because in my case `exit` looked like it wasn't working. I have since found out that was because I was creating a login shell (-I) and something in my `.bashrc` etc was creating extra bash instances that were hanging around in the background (thus preventing exit from killing off the cmd window).

Comment: Is there any way to automatically translate DOS line endings into Unix newlines?

Comment: @PythonNut In which situation do you want this? Looks like a more general question and not specific to my answer.

Comment: @galmok I mean in the situation where I am making this batch file with tools that only write DOS line endings (like notepad). How can I modify the script so it still runs without issue?

Comment: You would need to use dos2unix and unix2dos to convert newlines between unix and windows. The script working on the files needs unix style newlines and the script itself also needs to be with unix style newlines.

Comment: thanks! great stuff I would not have known this was possible.  makes every batch script a bash script:-)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to open the script in a mintty windows aswell, this (based on @galmok's answer) will do the trick.

```
: <<TRAMPOLINE
@echo off
C:\Users\user\Downloads\cyg-packages\bin\bash -c "exit 0" || (echo.No bash found in PATH! & exit /b 1)
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%i in (%*) do set _args= !_args! "%%~i"
C:\Users\user\Downloads\cyg-packages\bin\mintty.exe -i /Cygwin-Terminal.ico C:\Users\user\Downloads\cyg-packages\bin\bash -l "%~f0" "%CD%" %_args%
goto :EOF 
TRAMPOLINE
#####################
#!/bin/bash  -- it's traditional!
cd "$1"
shift
echo Working from $PWD
vim "$@"
```

Note: my use-case was the need to open a terminal vim from Visual Studio, which is why there is a call to `vim` at the end.  The batch file will exit afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

What kind of shell script? Bash? If you need to run a bash script, just run it with bash.exe via a shortcut. The target would be something like:

```
C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe foo.bsh
```

The path to bash.exe will depend on where cygwin was installed. (You don't need the path at all if the bin directory is in your path environment variable.)

You can do the same thing in a batch script if you want. The command line would be the same as "target" above.

---

**EDIT BASED ON COMMENTS** (still assuming bash):

Ok, so in your batch script (.bat) just type:

```
bash.exe script.txt
```

You may need to add the path to "bash.exe". If you're not sure where "bash.exe" is, open the "Cygwin.bat" file you mentioned in your question. It should have the path in a `chdir` command. (Note: Cygwin.bat is just running bash.exe in interactive mode. It's not really running anything named "cygwin".)

You will also need to add the path to "script.txt" if it isn't in the same directory as your batch script.

Again this will also work in a shortcut instead of a batch script.

Comment: Well, I want to run a shell script. But I don't want to have to open Cywgin then type all that stuff to execute it. I'd rather just run a batch file to open cygwin and then do it that way if possible.

Comment: @Aaron - Type all what stuff? Any command line, including command line args, you use to execute the script in cygwin can be added to the shortcut or to the batch script. Cygwin won't open, but a cmd window will. It should close when the script has finished running.

Comment: I have a shell script that I run in cygwin. I was wondering if I could create a batch file that would do it all for me instead of typing it all? But I am unsure how to use cygwin in the batch file.

Comment: @Aaron - It will depend on a couple of things. The most important is the type of shell script. Is it bash? When you run the script in cygwin, what do you have to type to get it to run? I can try to update my answer with a batch script for you to try.

Comment: Oh I just type "./script.txt" to make it run.

Comment: @Aaron - Please see my update. If this still doesn't make sense I'm not sure how else to explain it.

Comment: Works like a charm! Is there a way to make the output of the cygwin terminal appear in the windows terminal?

Answer (score 0):

To run "your_bash_file" from any .bat file, write following line to .bat:

git-bash.exe (path_to_your_bash_file>)

P.S. Windows Git is necessary installed